# creating a firestore rule based on whether the user is in a users array

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have a react native app that allows users to create a "sharedRide". Users in the shared ride can share their location and view other riders location on a map.

I'm trying to create a firestore rule that only allows users in the "invitedRiders" or "acceptedRiders" arrays to view that particular document and post coordinate updates in a sub-collection called "lastCoords". I expected "request.auth.uid in resource.data.xxxx" to work, but not very familiar with firestore rules yet and this isn't working. The main issue is that a rider that is removed from the sharedRide can still view the location of the active users.

rule I have been trying:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /sharedRide/{sharedRideID=**} {
      allow read, write: if 
          request.auth.uid in resource.data.invitedRiders ||
            request.auth.uid in resource.data.acceptedRiders
    }
  }
}
```

schema:

```
...
users
sharedRide
   -sharedRideID
      lastCoords (sub-collection)
      -acceptedRiders: []
      -invitedRiders: []
```

[schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBVSE.jpg)

snippet from redux slice that adds friend to the invitedFriends array:

```js
    addSelectedSharingFriends: (state, action) => {
      const [userID, groupRideID, currentUser]: [
        string,
        string,
        FriendUserData
      ] = action.payload
      state.invitedFriends.push(userID)
      firestore()
        .collection("sharedRide")
        .doc(groupRideID)
        .update({
          invitedRiders: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(userID),
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err))
    },
```

function when user accepts the ride invitation (moves them from invitedRiders to acceptedRiders array. It then creates a field in the lastCoords sub-collection to where their coordinates will be saved/updated during the ride.

```js
  const joinRide = (groupID: string): void => {
    Alert.alert(
      "Join Shared Ride?",
      "If accepted, your location will be seen by all riders in the group",
      [
        {
          text: "Cancel",
        },
        {
          text: "Accept",
          onPress: async () => {
            try {
              await firestore()
                .collection("sharedRide")
                .doc(groupID)
                .update({
                  invitedRiders: firestore.FieldValue.arrayRemove(
                    currentUser.userID
                  ),
                  acceptedRiders: firestore.FieldValue.arrayUnion(
                    currentUser.userID
                  ),
                })
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
            }
            try {
              await firestore()
                .collection("sharedRide")
                .doc(groupID)
                .collection("lastCoords")
                .doc(currentUser.userID)
                .set({
                  latitude: null,
                  longitude: null,
                  altitude: null,
                  lastUpdate: null,
                  fname: currentUser.fname,
                  lname: currentUser.lname,
                  batteryLevel: null,
                  maxSpeed: null,
                  totalDistance: null,
                })
            } catch (error) {
              console.log(error)
            }
            navigation.navigate("Map")
            if (!record) {
              dispatch(startRecord())
            }
            dispatch(newGroupRide(groupID))
          },
        },
      ]
    )
  }
```

Comment: Can you show the client side code and the documents' content?

Comment: the picture attached in my question shows the document structure. I can provide client side code, but not sure what you are looking for in specific? The firestore calls or... ? Basically just trying to figure out the security rule for the sharedRideID documents for someone that isn't listed in the invitedRiders or acceptedRiders array.

Comment: Rules by themselves don't mean much without knowing the data and the client side code

Comment: sounds good, in my edits I added a snipped from the redux slice handling the shared ride invitation, then the function to join a ride. Thanks for the help!